# Nested queries using wpdb

Tags: mysql, foreach, wordpress

Im trying to display a few rows of data for each `<h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>` item that appears in the loop.

With the current code it only shows one row for each item `<h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>`

I have this in my functions.php file
     `$newdb = new wpdb('login', 'pass', 'db', 'host');`

```
<?php $result=$newdb->get_results('select tbl1.name, tbl2.col1, tbl2.col2, tbl2.col3 from tbl1, tbl2 where tbl1.name=tbl2.tbl1_name');
$names=array();
foreach($result as $row): ?>
<?php $names[$row->name][]=$row;
endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($names as $name=>$info): ?>

    <h3><?php echo $name; ?></h3>
    <table>
       <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
        <?php foreach($info as $n):?>       
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $n->col1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $n->col2; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $n->col3; ?></td>    
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So the loop displays the heading followed by a few rows of records, not just one.

```
<h2>Name</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
        col1-value1  col2-value1  col3-value1
        col1-value2  col1-value2  col1-value2
        etc.
</table>

<h2>Name</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
        col1-value1  col2-value1  col3-value1
        col1-value2  col1-value2  col1-value2
        etc.
</table>

<h2>Name</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th></tr>
        col1-value1  col2-value1  col3-value1
        col1-value2  col2-value2  col3-value2
        etc.
</table>
.....`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using your idea but you can do it using one query like

```
global $wpdb;
$result=$wpdb->get_results('select a.col, b.col1, b.col2, b.col3 from a,b where a.col=b.col5');
```

Assume that you have `tbl1` table and it has a `name` field and `tbl2` table and it has a field for example `tbl1_name` which has the name value of `tbl1` name field and other fields,  (with no duplicates) so you can join both tables like

```
$result=$wpdb->get_results('select tbl1.name, tbl2.col1, tbl2.col2, tbl2.col3 from tbl1, tbl2 where tbl1.name=tbl2.tbl1_name');
$names=array();
foreach($result as $row): ?>
    $names[$row->name][]=$row;
<?php endforeach; ?>
foreach($names as $name=>$info):
    echo $name;
    ?><table><?php
    foreach($info as $n):
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $n->col1; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $n->col2; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $n->col3; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    ?></table><?php
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Also remember `$wpdb` is a global object and available through the template files so you dont need to use `new` to make an instanse, just use `global` keyword as I wrote in my answer.

[**Class Reference/wpdb**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [**sql join**](http://www.datamartist.com/sql-inner-join-left-outer-join-full-outer-join-examples-with-syntax-for-sql-server) and [**this one**](http://w3resource.com/sql/joins/sql-joins.php).

Comment: Thanks for your input, I tired your code but it only returns one row for each name entry from table 1 (tbl1.name). Each name entry will have a couple of rows in the html table that is returned by the foreach loop - currently it only displays one row. Im assuming there should be two queries?

Comment: Thanks Ive updated my question with your answer (thanks for the tip). the problem is I get 'unexpected T_ENDFOREACH' for the second last foreach (line 18 of your code).

Comment: @user1515699, sorry, it was my mistake, there was missing `:` after `foreach` statement and also `$row->name` should be `$name`. I've updated the answer, please check it again. Thanks.